# Is android software version is out of date

Tags: android

I want to know if the device software version is out of date.
Is it possible?
I know I can get the current version but how can I know if the device has a software update to make?
Can I prompt the update dialog either?

Comment: If I'm getting this right, Settings > About Phone > System Updates ?

Comment: Yeah,I can use an intent to redirect to about phone,but failed to redirect to the update screen or show the update dialog.